# How to create a custom file upload button in Angular

Tags: angular, input, file-upload

I'd like to replace the "Choose File" text and ugly styling of the `<input type="file" />` button with some other text such as "Upload" and nice styling, perhaps using a `mat-button`. What is the cleanest way to achieve this without installing any extra file-upload packages?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use below template:

.html:

```html
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">
  <span>Upload</span>
  <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onFileInput($event)" style="display:none;" />
</button>
```

The on-click function will prompt the user to select a file.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Btw, any difference putting `button` and `input` side-by-side instead of nesting the `input` inside `button`?

Comment: No problem! I believe there's no difference.

Comment: Perfect @PeterKim - exactly what I needed to. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks.  This is awesome

Comment: The greatest answer of all times. Thanks a lot. Upvoted